# how to write an entire list to a data structure in python

Tags: python, class, pandas, data-structures

So the problem I am facing is that I want to create a datastructure which have like 46 items from my pandas dataframe.
So I have the entire list of column name and have pandas dataframe in place.

So is there anyway that we can transform each row of pandas into an object of my datastructure.

So say:

I have an excel where

Col    X    Y
A      1    2
B      3     4
C      5     6

So i want to transform each row into an object

Is there some good method to do so considering I have 46 columns and like 100,000 of rows.

Comment: Iterate over the rows of the dataframe, make an object from each row, put the resulting objects in a list.

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: excel file as in ? xlsx or something sort of a csv/tsv that you opened in excel?

Comment: @Sword it's an xlsx file

Comment: And what kind of an object do you want? List of lists, dictionaries with 1st column values as keys or anything else in mind?

Comment: @Sword a class object with all the columns as its member variables.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, your pandas dataframe is called df

```
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    single_row = list(row)
    print(single_row) # or whatever you want to do with it.
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually each row in data frame itself is built on a data structure Numpy array.

```
df
Out[41]: 
    a   b
0   1   4
1   2   5
2 NaN NaN
3   3   6

df.loc[1].values
Out[42]: array([ 2.,  5.])

df.loc[1].values.dtype
Out[43]: dtype('float64')


df.loc[1].values.tolist()
Out[45]: [2.0, 5.0]
```

If you want all to be created iterate over index to get result